# Using a variable outside of a query, but keeping it specific to the query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am querying a table in a DB and displaying the info in rows; I am using the rowid from the query as the ID for the div so I can work with each individual div using jQuery:

```
while($row_cat = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$rowid=$row_cat['rowid'];
$id1=$row_cat['mgap_ska_id'];
?> 
<div id="name_<?php echo $rowid; ?>" class="<?php echo ($accept == '1')?'showop':'show';?>">
<span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $id1;  ?></span>
<span class="decline"><a href="#" data-dropdown="#dropdown-1">HIDE THIS DIV</a></span>
</div>                
<?php
}
```

I am using the jQuery bootstrap plugin to add a dropdown menu to my button. The plugin info is here:http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

Here is the dropdown; it is to be located at the bottom of the page (outside of the query presents the issue:

```
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#1"><span class="hidediv">Option One</span></a></li>   
        <li><a href="#2"><span class="hidediv">Option Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#3"><span class="hidediv">Option Three</span></a></li>     
    </ul>
```

and Im using the following simple jQuery to hide a div...as long as the div selector I KNOWN...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".decline").click(function(){
  $("THIS NEEDS TO BE MY ROWID").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

here is my issue: How do I pass the dynamic row id ($rowid) to jQuery if:

A. The dropdown and the jQuery are both outside of the WHILE and thus $rowid would be not valid outside of the query.

B. The variable HAS to remain specific to each row; Im hiding the entire row after the link in the dropdown for that specific row has been clicked.

Comment: html id must start with a letter

Comment: Which div are you trying to hide exactly? Once decline is clicked which div should be animated/hidden?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Gary. Im trying to hide the div that is within the query (keep in mind there are numerous rows) that the users chooses. Each row is contained in its own div and each row has a link to a dropdown (this contains links that will eventually pass data back to the DB. When a user clicks on the link in a row, they get the dropdown, make a selection, and the same row with the link that was clicked on is then hidden when they click on their selection in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead add a class and use the class for your jQuery selector,

```
jQuery('.myclass').each(function () {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); // if you need the row id
    jQuery(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow"); //or whatever you wanna do

});
```

**UPDATE:**
As @hakre pointed out, we could use the partial attribute value matching ("starting with") but in your case what you want to do is really something like that:

```
jQuery('.decline').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).parent('div').animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
});
```

And you put it outside of every loop. This code should appear only once.

Comment: You don't need that. partial attribute value matching ("starting with") does the job here already: attribute name: "id", starting with: "name_". Why stick more to it if it's already there?

Comment: @user1855163 - I would add this within the DIV within WHILE - correct?

Comment: Thanks for your input. In my case the parent div of the selector is located at the bottom of the page, not within the structure of the row. Which is why I was trying to use the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the events that the dropdown plugin provies for `show` and `hide` which holds in the `dropdownData` variable the original target that caused the dropdown to show.

```
(function($) {
    var $dropdownTrigger = $();

    $('#dropdown-1').on('show', function(event, dropdownData) {
        // Get the original element that caused the dropdown to appear
        // and set it for use later
        $dropdownTrigger = dropdownData.trigger;
    });

    $('#dropdown-1').on('hide', function(event, dropdownData) {
        // Get the original element that caused the dropdown to appear
        // and find the closest .name-container div to animate it
        $dropdownTrigger
            .closest('div.name-container')
            .animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
            .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

You will need to add a class of `name-container` to your div inside the query loop:

```
<div id="name_<?php echo $rowid; ?>" class="name-container <?php echo ($accept == '1')?'showop':'show';?>">
```